# Simulate mouse clicks on openlayer-3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

Trying to simulate mouse clicks on a open layer-3 map. I've tried the usual jquery click on co-ordinates but that does not seem to work.

What I tried:

```
function simulateClick(x, y) {
jQuery(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).click();
}
simulateClick(450,820);
```

Does not want to click a open layers map. I want it to draw an object in case you are wondering.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: what about to have a look their testing code? https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/83f87a1f1ee4d9a2e1e3954c908188c8a73cfb75/test/spec/ol/interaction/draw.test.js#L68

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems like the stuff I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The link that @Chase Choi provided allows the ability to simulate a user in open layers map... [Here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/83f87a1f1ee4d9a2e1e3954c908188c8a73cfb75/test/spec/ol/interaction/draw.test.js#L68)